# How to prove or disprove the expression of the index of a subgroup?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, group-actions

Let $L=\mathbb Z^2$, $\gamma\in \mathrm M_2(\mathbb Z)$, $\det (\gamma)=n>0$. Then $\gamma$ acts on $L$ by left matrix multiplication. Is $[L:\gamma L]=n$?

I have tried proving this by Fundamental Theorem on Homomorphisms but have not made any progress. I think I can solve the case only when $n=1$.

What's more, it seems that when $L=\mathbb Z^k(k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq1})$ the claim is also true. How to prove the generalized proposition? The case $k=1$ is equivalent to $|\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z|=n$.

Comment: Note: "prove" & "proof" are different words, as are "disprove" & "disproof".

Comment: What is $|\gamma|$, if not $\det(\gamma)$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde $|\gamma|$ is $\det(\gamma)$ here.

Comment: do you know Smith normal form?  That could be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reduce $\gamma$ to Smith Normal Form using unimodular row and column operations. These do not change $|L:\gamma(L)|$ and they do not change $|\det(\gamma)|$, so you can assume that $\gamma$ is diagonal, and then the result is clear.